# How to Translate form on createView?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I create a form:

```
$data = new Task();
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $data);

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'name'
            ])
        /* .... */
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
       'data_class' => Task::class,
        'translation_domain' => 'task'
    ]);
}
```

But after `$form->createView()` my labels in form not translated. 
In config.yml i enable translator:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

in app/Resources/translations/task.ru.yml:

```
name: Название задачи
responsible: Ответственный
status: Статус
dateStart: Начало
planDateEnd: Окончание
description: Описание
dayCount: Число дней
file: Документы
notifications: Уведомления
watchers: Наблюдателе
complete: '% завершения'
```

I can translate labels without send translator component in form class?

Comment: Did you check the profiler toolbar? It has an icon for missing translations, that could help you debug the issue. Can you post how your translation file looks?

Comment: do you have the file app/Resources/translations/task.xx.yy ? xx = locale, yy = extension

Comment: and do you have translation enabled in your config.yml ? Is the default language set on the language that you prefer?

Comment: Yes. I enable translation in config.yml
    
   ` framework:
        translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }`

`task.ru.yml : 
task:
    name: Название задачи
    responsible: Ответственный
    status: Статус
    dateStart: Начало
    planDateEnd: Окончание
    description: Описание
    dayCount: Число дней
    file: Документы
    notifications: Уведомления
    watchers: Наблюдателе
    complete: '% завершения'`

Comment: And you sure your locale param is set to "ru"?

Comment: @Code717, yes. If i render form in template my field translated. But i want translate label on createView, because i send this to react and generate form there

Comment: read this : https://blog.elao.com/en/dev/a-nice-way-of-handing-form-label-translation/

Comment: @Hiren Makwana, this bundle build translation key, but not apply translation

Answer (score 0):

You could manually translate the labels after $form->createView().

(Code untested)

```
$view = $form->createView();
$trans = $this->get('translator');

foreach ($view->children as $name => $child)
{
    if (isset($child->vars['label']))
    {
        $view->children[$name]->vars['label'] = $trans->trans($child->vars['label']);
    }
}
```

Comment: This i know. I want automatically translate at createView.

Comment: You could write a service for that